# Dash XSD namespace mapping

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have made the following XML schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                      
<xs:schema                                                                                  
    targetNamespace="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"                                         
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                                             
    xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013"                                                         
    xmlns:mspr="urn:microsoft:playready"                                                    
    elementFormDefault="qualified"                                                          
>                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <xs:element name="ContentProtection">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>                                                     
          <xs:element name="pssh" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="pro" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="schemeIdUri" type="xs:string" />       
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm trying to understand how to do the correct mapping so that when I generate a XJC episode file, I get a mapping such that JAXB knows that the `pssh` XML element belongs to the "urn:mpeg:cenc:2013" namespace and the `pro` XML element belongs to the "urn:microsoft:playready" namespace.

Basically, I need my deserialized class to end up like:

```
  @XmlElement(namespace = "urn:mpeg:cenc:2013", required = true)
  protected String pssh;
  @XmlElement(namespace = "urn:microsoft:playready", required = true)
  protected String pro;
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out...

Had to make my own `cenc` and `mspr` XML schemas and import them into the original one as types.

## cenc.xsd

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013"                                                                                                                                          
           attributeFormDefault="qualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">
    <xs:element name="pssh" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
</xs:schema>
```

## mspr.xsd

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn:microsoft:playready"                                                                                                                                     
           attributeFormDefault="qualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="urn:microsoft:playready">
    <xs:element name="pro" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
</xs:schema>
```

## ContentProtection.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                                                                                                                                   
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013"
    xmlns:mspr="urn:microsoft:playready"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    >

  <xs:import namespace="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013" schemaLocation="cenc.xsd"/>
  <xs:import namespace="urn:microsoft:playready" schemaLocation="mspr.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="ContentProtection">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="cenc:pssh"/>
          <xs:element ref="mspr:pro"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="schemeIdUri" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now JAXB deserializes everything correctly.